# How to find out two lists with same structure in python?

Tags: python, list, recursion

Define a procedure, same_structure, that takes two inputs. It should output
`True` if the lists have the same structure, and `False`
otherwise. Two values, p and q have the same structure if:

```
Neither p or q is a list.

Both p and q are lists, they have the same number of elements, and each
element of p has the same structure as the corresponding element of q.
```

EDIT: To make the picture clear the following are the expected output

```
same_structure([1, 0, 1], [2, 1, 2])
    ---> True
same_structure([1, [0], 1], [2, 5, 3])
    ---> False
same_structure([1, [2, [3, [4, 5]]]], ['a', ['b', ['c', ['d', 'e']]]])
    ---> True
same_structure([1, [2, [3, [4, 5]]]], ['a', ['b', ['c', ['de']]]])
    ---> False
```

I thought recursion would be best to solve this problem in python I have come up with the following code but its not working.

```
def is_list(p):
    return isinstance(p, list)

 def same_structure(a,b):
    if not is_list(a) and not is_list(b):
        return True
    elif is_list(a) and is_list(b):
        if len(a) == len(b):
            same_structure(a[1:],b[1:])
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: @SvenMarnach: unless I'm misreading the question, [2,(3,4)] and [2, (5,)] have the same structure: they're both lists, they have the same number of elements, and each element of p has the same structure as the corresponding element of q because neither is a list.  IOW it's only the list structure that matters, the values don't (so that [2] and [3] have the same structure too.)

Comment: Define "same structure" for a list as for python ['a', '1'] is not equal to ['1', 'a']. Maybe you'd be better using sets too.

Comment: In this context though I think I *would* say they contain the same elements, where equality is defined by the given relation.  I think I had a question like this myself, back in the day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recursion *would* be a good idea, but not the way you've suggested it. First off (and this may be only a typo), you don't actually return anything here:

```
if len(a) == len(b):
    same_structure(a[1:],b[1:])
```

Second, you should recursively deal with each element, not each sublist. ie.:

```
if len(a) == len(b):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if not same_structure(a[i], b[i]):
            return False
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of `same_structure(a[1:],b[1:])`, you need to check item pair of a and b *one by one*

```
def is_list(p):
    return isinstance(p, list)

def same_structure(a, b):
    if not is_list(a) and not is_list(b):
        return True
    elif (is_list(a) and is_list(b)) and (len(a) == len(b)):
        return all(map(same_structure, a, b)) # Here
    return False
```

Answer (score 5):

You're missing one case, and forgot to return in the second case. Notice that is not necessary to explicitly compare the lengths of the lists, as the first case takes care of this - if one of the lists is empty and the other not, it's because one list had fewer elements than the other:

```
def same_structure(a, b):
    if a == [] or b == []:  # one of the lists is empty
        return a == b       # are both of the lists empty?
    elif is_list(a[0]) != is_list(b[0]):
        return False        # one of the elements is a list and the other is not
    elif not is_list(a[0]): # neither element is a list
        return same_structure(a[1:], b[1:])
    else:                   # both elements are lists
        return same_structure(a[0], b[0]) and same_structure(a[1:], b[1:])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but its not working because of integer comparison in second condition

Comment: Kindly see expected output in question you will understand.

Comment: @UmeshKacha the second condition?, you men this: `is_list(a[0]) != is_list(b[0])`. That's not an integer comparison, it's a boolean comparison. What that line says is: "if one of the elements is a list and the other is not a list, then return False, because the structure is different"

Comment: @UmeshKacha as a matter of fact, I tested my solution with _all_ of the examples in your question and it works perfectly, for all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Since the specification says that the input are two lists, you can iterate the lists inside your function without further checks, and only do recursive calls if you encounter sublists:

```
def same_structure(a, b):
    if len(a) != len(b):
        return False
    return all(is_list(x) and is_list(y) and same_structure(x, y) or
               not is_list(x) and not is_list(y)
               for x, y in zip(a, b))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way too also, check the type of both lists & length of both lists
and do this recursively for sub-lists of both list.

```
def same_structure(a,b):
    return isinstance(a, list) and isinstance(b, list) and len(a) == len(b)  
    and all(same_structure_as(c, d) for c, d in zip(a, b) if isinstance(c, list))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.